# Error en WPF: System.InvalidOperationException al cerrar una ventana

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un programa que tiene la ventana principal y varios botones que abren una ventana secundaria, lo que pasa es que cuando cierro la ventana secundaria y la quiero volver a abrir me sale el error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.'
Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window1 nueva = new Window1(); //Nueva ventana

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Tengo dos botones que abren la misma ventana pero con diferente
    // contenido dependiendo del botón que presione
    private void Boton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        nueva.Show();
        nueva.LabelWin2.Content = "Boton1";
    }

    private void Boton2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        nueva.Show();
        nueva.LabelWin2.Content = "Boton2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería conveniente que muestres el código para saber, pero mi primera impresión es que estás implementando mal la ventana. Es realmente una ventana? es un cuadro de dialogo? lo llamas con Show()? o con ShowDialog? lo estás creando con "new" cada vez que abres una nueva ventana?, la cierras con el botón? o con DialogResult? es una ventana de acceso a nivel de clase o está definida dentro del método? Tienes definido algún evento de la ventana como Closing? Aclaramos un poco tu caso.

Comment: Ya agregué código, si puedes checarlo

Comment: Agrega = new Window1(); antes del Show(), pues si cierras la ventana el GC la eliminará de la memoria, así que simplemente deja de existir, la instancia que tienes creada arriba solo sirve para abrirla 1 vez, y sobre lo mismo, si agregas el = new Window1(); antes de cada show no necesitas ponerlo arriba. El error que mencionas es porque quieres mostrar una ventana que ya está descargada de la memoria.